# How can I change the invalid characters to valid chars in Java?

Tags: java, regex

```
 private static void isValidName(String[] filename){
    FileSystem fs  = FileSystems.getDefault();
    System.out.println(fs);

    String pattern = ("^[\\w&[^?\\\\/. ]]+?\\.*[\\w&[^?\\\\/. ]]+$");               

    for (String s: filename) {
        //System.out.println(s.matches(pattern));
        if (s.matches(pattern)==false){

            System.out.println(s.matches(pattern));

        }
    }
```

Now I call this function:

```
 String[] name2={"valami.txt."};
 isValidName(name2);
```

How can I replace the invalid characters in `if(s.matches(pattern)==false)`  with valid characters?

Output:
`false`

Comment: please, be more specific. What is the problem? Which characters are invalid? what do you want to do? If you just want to replace invalid characters into some valid ones, you can use replaceAll for example

Comment: I guess it is a continuation of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027805/how-can-i-write-a-more-complex-regexp-in-java). So, what should the replacement look like? A `_` character for all invalid characters?

Comment: Not begining with space " ", not more than one "." , not begining with "." not end with "." not ? / \ : ; in the file.
And yes stribizhev replace with _  for example.

Comment: @kokoko duplicate questions are flagged for deletion.

Comment: its not same question....

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150850/how-to-convert-strings-in-any-language-and-character-set-to-valid-filenames-in-j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this piece of code to remove/replace invalid characters:

```
String[] bad = {
     "foo.tar.gz",
     " foo.txt",
     "foo?",
     "foo/",
     "foo\\",
     ".foo",
     "foo."
   };
  String remove_pattern = "^[ .]+|\\.+$|\\.(?=[^.]*\\.[^.]*$)|[?\\\\/:;]"; 
  for (String s: bad) {
       System.out.println(s.replaceAll(remove_pattern, "_"));
  }
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/RqyTxI)

Output:

```
foo_tar.gz
_foo.txt
foo_
foo_
foo_
_foo
foo_
```

**REGEX** contains several alternatives joined with `|` alternation operator to match the invalid character(s) only.

- `^[ .]+` - Matches 1 or more leading spaces or dots
- `\\.+$` - Matches final `.`, 1 or more occurrences (change to `[. ]+$` if you plan to also replace trailing spaces)
- `\\.(?=[^.]*\\.[^.]*$)` - Matches a `.` that is followed by an optional number of characters and another dot (thus, leaving the last dot in the string)
- `[?\\\\/:;]` - Matches `?`, `\`, `/`, `:` and `;` literally.